# In R, how to make a variable which indicates when the value occurs

Tags: r

I would like to make a variable "qualification_first" in the below "df2" in the panel dataset.

How to make it?

```
df1 <- data.frame(id = c("Tony"),
                  year = 2015:2020,
                  qualification = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1))

df2 <- data.frame(id = c("Tony"),
                  year = 2015:2020,
                  qualification_first = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0))
```

Comment: I am guessing you have more than 1 id?

Comment: `qualification_first` takes value 1 in the first year in which the participant qualified? What is this `qualification_first`?

Comment: Maybe `as.integer(c(df1[1, "qualification"] != 0L, diff(df1$qualification) > 0L))`. The task isn't well defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another way to do it assuming that `qualification` always goes from `0` to `1` and not above.

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  mutate(qualification_first = if_else(lag(qualification, default = 0) != qualification, 1, 0),
         .by = id)

#>     id year qualification qualification_first
#> 1 Tony 2015             0                   0
#> 2 Tony 2016             0                   0
#> 3 Tony 2017             0                   0
#> 4 Tony 2018             1                   1
#> 5 Tony 2019             1                   0
#> 6 Tony 2020             1                   0
```

Data from OP

```r
df1 <- data.frame(id = c("Tony"),
                  year = 2015:2020,
                  qualification = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(qualification_first = +(row_number() == match(1, qualification))) %>%
  ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 × 4
  id     year qualification qualification_first
  <chr> <int>         <dbl>               <int>
1 Tony   2015             0                   0
2 Tony   2016             0                   0
3 Tony   2017             0                   0
4 Tony   2018             1                   1
5 Tony   2019             1                   0
6 Tony   2020             1                   0
```

---

Or use `duplicated`

```
df1 %>%
   mutate(qualification_first = +(!duplicated(pick(id, 
      qualification)) & qualification == 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also play with row numbers(`.I`) in `data.table`.

```
library(data.table)

first <- setDT(df1)[qualification==1,.I[1L], by=id]$V1
df1[,qualification_first := ifelse(.I %in% first, 1,0)][]
```

**output**

```
 Index: <qualification>
        id  year qualification qualification_first
    <char> <int>         <num>               <num>
 1:   Tony  2015             0                   0
 2:   Tony  2016             0                   0
 3:   Tony  2017             0                   0
 4:   Tony  2018             1                   1
 5:   Tony  2019             1                   0
 6:   Tony  2020             1                   0
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>